# Server unstable after a WHM automated update

Tags: web-server

I have a server with WHM/cPanel server a website (Apache, PHP, MySQL) and a few days ago WHM performed some kind of update on itself (there are new icons and new appearance overall). Ever since that day, my site has been running slow for shorts periods of time, but several times a day. That never happend before.

Is there some common cause for this? Something that WHM does when it does an update?
I'm really clueless about this problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your log processing is executed often enough. Access logs may grow very fast if your site has high traffic, and when that happens, processing the logs for getting the stastics (awstats, Webalizer, etc..) can take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more details about your setup, and what exactly was updated by WHM.
Depending on your WHM configuration (see your update preferences), Mysql might be updated with the latest minor version upgrade.
If that's the case, then run a `CHECK TABLE tabl_name FOR UPGRADE` statement on your tables to make sure they are compatible with the new mysql version.

Comment: Looking at the system logs, it seems that Mysql has been updated several times during the past year. I wasn't aware of WHM doing that.